# replace a specific character within a list of strings using list comprehension

Tags: python, string, list, replace, list-comprehension

```
my_list = ['"r&d"', '"clinical trial"']
```

**my desired output**

```
my_list = ['"r%26d"', '"clinical trial"']
```

**my code attempt 1:**

```
my_list = [char.replace('&',"%26") for char in item for item in my_list]
```

**result 1**

```
my_list = ['"r&d"', '"clinical trial"']
```

**my code attempt 2:**

```
my_list = [[char.replace('&',"%26") for char in item] for item in my_list]
```

**result 2**

```
[['r', '%26', 'd'], ['c', 'l', 'i', 'n', 'i', 'c', 'a', 'l', ' ', 't', 'r', 'i', 'a', 'l']]
```

I would like to use list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single for is enough in the list comprehension:

```
[item.replace('&',"%26") for item in my_list]
# ['"r%26d"', '"clinical trial"']
```